# React native insert a React node inside Text?

Tags: react-native

**My use case:**
I'm trying to create a button component, so the children of the component are of ReactNode type, usually string but it could be anything.

Then in my Button component, when I render the children, I wrap them in `<Text>` in case they're a string, but if they're not if they are for example a bunch of `<View>` since they're nested inside `<Text>`, they'll appear in one line

**My question:**
If I have for example

```
  <Text>
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>There</Text>
    </View>
  </Text>
```

How can I have the Hello and There appear on two different lines?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{'\n'}` newline character between them ?

```js
<Text>
  <View>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
  {'\n'}
  <View>
    <Text>There</Text>
  </View>
</Text>
```

---

To answer the comment:

Not directly, but with a tricky way, something like this, mapping through the elements wrapped within the button i.e `children` and apply the disred styling to their wrapper `View` component, since children can be of different node types so we use the `View` as a container and style it :

```js
const Button = ({ children }) => {
return (
 <View style={{...}}> 
  {Array.isArray(children) ? (
        children.map((child, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={{...}}>
            {child}
          </View>
        ))
   ) : (
        <Text style={{...}}>{children}</Text>
   )}
 </View>
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I didn't know it this was a legit way to go since I might want to create a flex container with gap (as an example) in contrast with a simple line break. But it's certainly something to work with

Comment: @sir-haver honestly I will go with flex styling since it gives you more control but this is the easiest way to do it ^^

Comment: Yes but you can't, if the View(s) are inside the Text, flex won't work on them, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't understand your answer, strings cannot be wrapped in <View>, you cannot do <View>Hello</View>, you must wrap it in Text

Answer (score 0):

You can have both Text field inside a same View without wrapping them in separate Views like below,

```js
<View>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
  <Text>There</Text>
</View>
```

And it will appear in different lines.